# How to subtract more than 2 numbers

Tags: c#, console-application

i am trying to make simple calculation and taking input of my own choice to subtract using loop but result is not coming true..

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Enter how many numbers u want to perform operations?");
int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 1; i <= b; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter " + i + " Number");
    c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int s = s - c;
}
Console.WriteLine("Result is={0}", s);
```

Comment: Assign int s; out of you for loop scope as it is getting reinitialise on every interation.

Comment: And please use zero base convention. Your loop should be: `for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)` or you are in for a whole lot of pain when you start dealing with strings, arrays, etc.

Comment: If this is all of your code, it shouldn't even compile

Comment: Does your code actually compile? In the code you've shown us you haven't declared `c` and `s` is being used in the last line in a place where it is not actually in scope. Additionally the line where you do `int s = s - c;` is using s when it hasn't been initialzed. Given the solution to your code involves changing how s is used its hard to answer your question because any answers we give can only be based on the code above which is clearly not your actual code or it wouldn't be that the result was wrong but that your code didn't compile at all...

Comment: #Chris i intialize all variables above in my project..so thats not the issue..

Comment: the main issue is that if i apply same mechanism for addition it work perfectly but in case of subtraction it not give me correct result..it add up values and give result in negative

Comment: In addition to all the other problems people have mentioned: use `TryParse`, not `Parse`, for human-entered numbers. That way if they make a mistake, your program does not crash.

Comment: no bro this is not the issue of try parse

Comment: Why you don't present the actual code that has "the issue" so that people can help?

Comment: i already present the code....

Comment: i change the code and initialize s outside the loop but it cant work

Comment: @hashirkhan well, If you need help you should clearly describe your problem. When you say "this is not the issue" or "this is not working" you need to describe clearly "what is your main issue?" or give an example of inputs and output and describe why the output is not what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

In every iteration you're declaring the `s` again. You need to declare the `s` variable outside of your loop, also I don't know where have you declared `c`, if you have declared it outside of your loop, it's fine, however unlike `s` you can define `c` inside your loop if you didn't declare it already:

```
int s = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= b; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter " + i + " Number");
    int c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    s = s-c;//Or simpler s -= c;
}
```

In this way, the `s` will also be available when you are calling the following line outside of your loop:

```
Console.WriteLine("Result is={0}", s);
```

Comment: its not working bro..i already declare int s=0; outside my loop

Comment: @hashirkhan No. you have declared `s` inside your loop. See this line in your code: `int s = s - c;`

Comment: bro i know this...to copy and paste here i initialize variable in this way..in my project i initialize it outside of my loop

Comment: i initialize int s=0; outside of my loop in my project..so this is not the issue

Comment: @hashirkhan You are asking some stranger to spend some of his time solving your problem but you seem unable to make the effort of actually updating your question with the real code you are running, a set of inputs and observed outputs and the expected behavior.

Comment: my issue is i am trying to subtract more than 2 numbers ......forexample when i take 3 numbers input from user to subtract then it show wrong result...here is my code..